# C++: Why will this not cause a dangling pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a dangling pointer

```
Foo* p;
{
  Foo f;
  p = &f;
}
// now p is dangling pointer
```

However, why is this not a dangling pointer?

```
Foo* p;
{
  Foo f;
  ...
  *p = f;
}
// p still contains the data of f
```

Is it because in the second case, we are doing a copy? Does this mean I should have written

```
*p = std::move(f);
```

if I do not want a copy?

Thank you!

Comment: This is ub. The pointer p is not initialized.

Comment: You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.  Does this not concern you?  The attempted copy goes where p is pointing, but where is p pointing?

Comment: Your first example _produces_ a dangling pointer, and your second example can effectively be considered as _already being_ a dangling pointer.  Even though it's not technically meeting the definition of "dangling" it is nonetheless equally unusable.

Comment: In the second vase, `p` is an uninitialised pointer, so accessing its value (let alone dereferencing it via `*p`) gives undefined behaviour.    To do anything with `*p` without invoking undefined behaviour, it is necessary to initialise or assign `p` so it points at a valid object  (e.g.  `p = &some_object_that_exists;   *p = f;`)

Answer (score 2):

In your 2nd example `p` is uninitialized. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Indeed true, but if the question is "Why will this not cause a dangling pointer?", does this answer that question?

Comment: @DrewDormann the question is moot because because you cannot talk about the pointer being dangling or not  when the code exabits Undefined Behavior because of that same pointer not being initialized before use.

Comment: I agree with you.  This question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the behaviour well-defined by giving `p` a valid value (not leaving things uninitialized is the simplest, cheapest form of bug prevention):

```
Foo* p = new Foo;
{
    ...
```

or

```
Foo x;
Foo* p = &x;
{
    ...
```

Now, in your first piece of code, `p` stores the location of `f`, which has been destroyed.
This is what makes it a dangling pointer.

In the second, you don't change `p` but store the *value* of `f` in `*p`, which is the same object as it always was.
Since that object still exists, the pointer is not dangling.

Compare these two snippets:

```
int x = 0;
int* p = &x;
{
    int y = 1;
    p = &y;
}
std::cout << "p: " << p << ", &x: " << &x;
```

and

```
int x = 0;
int* p = &x;
{
    int y = 1;
    *p = y;
}
std::cout << "p: " << p << ", &x: " << &x;
```

and you will see that the first prints two different addresses, and the second prints the same address twice.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction - if any - depends on your definition of "dangling pointer".   And it is pretty academic.

**Discussion of one possible definition.**   One possible definition of a dangling pointer is "a pointer that points to data which is no longer valid".

By that definition, your first example;

> ```
> Foo* p;
> {
>   Foo f;
>   p = &f;
> }
> // now p is dangling pointer
> ```

results in `p` being a dangling pointer, because it points at the object `f`, and `f` ceases to exist at the end of its enclosing scope (i.e. the `}`).   Since `p` still exists, and its value is not changed in the process of `f` ceasing to exist, `p` now points at an object that no longer exists.

By that same definition, your second example;

> ```
> Foo* p;
> {
>   Foo f;
>   ...  
>   *p = f;
> }
> // p still contains the data of f
> ```

does not produce a dangling pointer, since `p` never pointed at a valid object.   In fact, `p` is uninitialised, so simply accessing its value produces undefined behaviour and its value (if any) is indeterminate.    Dereferencing (i.e. evaluating `*p`) cannot be done without evaluating `p` so the expression `*p` and the statement `*p = f` both give undefined behaviour.    Doing anything with `*p` after the `}` causes undefined behaviour (just as it does in your first example).

With this definition, The distinction of `p` being a dangling pointer in the first example and not in the second is a bit academic.    The difference is that, in the first case, `p` is considered a dangling pointer because it *no longer* points at a valid object but, in the second case, `p` is not considered a dangling pointer because it *never* pointed at a valid object.   Practically, the distinction makes no difference, since doing anything with `*p` gives undefined behaviour.

**Discussion of a second possible definition**   A second possible definition of a dangling pointer is subtly different to the first "a pointer that points at invalid data".

By this second definition, both of your examples produce a dangling pointer.  The first causes `p` to point at an object that no longer exists - so it points at invalid data.    In the second example, `p` never pointed at a valid object - so it also points at invalid data.    By this definition of a dangling pointer, `p` is a dangling pointer after the `}` in both examples because it *now* points at an invalid object.

The distinction under this second definition is still academic. Simply evaluating `*p` (let alone using it to change the invalid object `p` points at by, say, `*p = some_Foo`) gives undefined behaviour.